# How to show fixed no of ion-cards per row with same size?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want a display with fixed no of cards per row,and the cards should be in the same size.
[image: Current view]

**home.html**

```
   <ion-row>
     <ion-col *ngFor="let item of allservices; let i = index">
       <ion-card (click)="gotoSpecificService(item)">
         <img  src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/color/Gaming//snorlax1600.png"/>
         <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
```

I want the service 5,Service 6 should be in the same size as Service 2,3,4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ion-row {
        .col {
            max-width: 33%;
        }
    }
```

This you can put in the css based on the parent class of the page.